# Optimization problem, showing maximum number of remaining options given a collection of selections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization

My code solution currently doesn't cover all possibilities and is half baked... looking for helping completing!

**Background**

I have an apple basket with any number of attributes, and possible options for those attributes. For example, let's say the 3 attributes I choose to define, as well as the possible options, are:

```
- price: [1, 2, 5]
- size: [S, M, L]
- color: [Red, Green, Yellow]
```

In other words, the above says that there are 3 possible prices, 3 possible sizes, 3 possible colors that describe the apples in my basket. However, there's no information on quantity.

For example, this basket could be composed of 3 distinct apples:

```
- $1, small, red apple
- $2, medium, green apple
- $5, large, yellow apple
```

Or it could be composed of 12 apples as such:

```
- 3 $1, small, red apple
- 2 $1, small, green apples
- 2 $2, medium, green apples
- 4 $5, medium, yellow apples
- 1 $5, large, red apple
```

An important way of thinking about it is, if I were marketing this basket of apples, I want to market it such that the **maximum number of options are presented** (for the attributes I choose to define), regardless of how many counts of those options exist. In the last example, with the basket of 12 apples, I want to market that I have a `large-size` and a `red-color` even though those 2 options occur on a single given apple.

**Problem**

Given such a marketing strategy, when 1 person orders an apple, I want to give them the apple that meets their requirements while least-constraining the marketability of the rest of my basket. These 2 are kind of the inverse of each other. In my case, I am interested in calculating the greatest number of remaining options after they take their apple (rather than calculating which apple they should take).

3 examples for in the 12 apple basket scenarios above.

1. If someone orders a single $5 apple, I would for sure want to give them a medium yellow apple, rather than a large red apple, because once I give away my large red apple, `large-size` and `red-color` are permanently removed from the marketable options I have.
2. However, if someone orders a single $5 red apple, then alas, I have to give away the only large red apple I have, and therefore I lose both `large-size` and `red-color` from the list of marketable options
3. If someone orders a single $5 apple (example 1 above) and then a second person orders a large apple, once again I lose both `large-size` and `red-color`

Pseudo-code of the method & output:

```
def remaining_options(order); end

# basket = 12 apple objects as defined in sample scenario above

### EXAMPLE 1
basket.remaining_options([{price:5}])
=> {
  price: [1, 2, 5],
  size: [S, M, L],
  color: [Red, Green, Yellow]
}

basket.remaining_options([{price:5, color: red}])
=> {
  price: [1, 2, 5],
  size: [S, M],
  color: [Green, Yellow]
}

basket.remaining_options([{price:5}, {size: large}])
=> {
  price: [1, 2, 5],
  size: [S, M],
  color: [Green, Yellow]
}
```

**My solution**

Just playing around with the examples above, I thought about 2 possible options when someone orders.

1. Their order could be strict enough (e.g., they order using multiple attributes) that only 1 apple is available to them. In this case, all the attributes of that specific apple are deducted from the marketable list.
2. Their order could be loosely defined (e.g., they order on one attribute). In this case, only the ordered attribute is deducted from the marketable list

So here is my solution

```
# assume there is a model Apple for each apple in the basket where the defined attributes are attributes of the model object itself
# and where apples = basket of 12 apples described above

def remaining_options(order)
  # first, build a count of all basket options for defined attributes; count is independent of each other, since we're maximizing options
  defined_attributes = [:price, :size, :color]
  remaining_options = {}
  defined_attributes.each do |a|
    remaining_options[a] = apples.group(key).count
  end

  # result 
  # remaining_options = {
  #   price: {1=>2, 2=>1, 5=>1},
  #   size: {"S"=>2,"M"=>2,"L"=>1},
  #   color: {"Red"=>2,"Green"=>2,"Yellow"=>1}
  # }

  order.each do |o|
    matched_apples_from_basket = apples.where(o)
    if matched_apples_from_basket.size == 1
      # all attributes of this 1 apple must be subtracted non-independently; it's a capacity constraint
      matched_apple = matched_apples_from_basket.last
      remaining_options.each do |option, count_hash|
        remaining_options[option][matched_apple.send(option)] -= 1
      end
    else
      # loose constraint, we can still deduct independently
      o.each do |option, value|
        remaining_options[option][value] -= 1
      end
    end
  end

  remaining_options.each do |option, count_hash|
    remaining_options[option] = count_hash.reject { |v, count| count < 1 }.keys
  end

  return remaining_options
end
```

While this solution does work in the test example scenarios that I have mentioned (any errors are bad copy job... hopefully small, sorry), because the query runs on each ordered item independently, this fails when the collection of ordered items itself causes a constraint.

For example, if the order looked like this: `[{price:"5"},{price:"5"},{price:"5"},{price:"5"},{price:"5"}]`, my solution would take each query independently, and independently, $5 isn't a capacity constraint. So my solution would subtract $5 from the option set independently such that at the end, you'd have a remaining set of `{price:[1,2],size:["Small","Medium",Large"], color: ["Red", "Green", "Yellow"]}`

But this would be wrong, because as a whole, ordering 5 $5 apples means you take all of them, which creates a capacity constraint in the sense that now there will be no more yellow or large apples. So the result should actually be `{price:[1,2],size:["Small","Medium"], color: ["Red", "Green"]}`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have an array of hashes of such as the following:

```
basket = [
  { price: 1, size: :S, color: :red,    qty: 3 },
  { price: 1, size: :S, color: :green,  qty: 2 },
  { price: 2, size: :M, color: :green,  qty: 2 },
  { price: 4, size: :M, color: :pink,   qty: 0 },
  { price: 5, size: :M, color: :yellow, qty: 4 },
  { price: 5, size: :L, color: :red,    qty: 1 },
]
```

This corresponds to one of the examples given in the question, with one change: I added medium-size pink apples costing $4 for which the quantity on hand is zero. My reason for doing so will become clear.

We may compute the following:

```
def attributes(basket)
  basket.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    g.each do |attr,value|
      h[attr] = Hash.new(0) unless h.key?(attr)
      h[attr][value] += g[:qty] unless attr == :qty    
    end
  end
end
```

```
attr = attributes(basket)
  #=> {:price=>{1=>5, 2=>2, 4=>0, 5=>5},
  #    :size=>{:S=>5, :M=>6, :L=>1},
  #    :color=>{:red=>4, :green=>4, :pink=>0, :yellow=>4}}
```

For example, there are `6` apples with size `:M`:

```
basket[2][:qty] + basket[3][:qty] + basket[4][:qty]
  #=> 2 + 0 + 4 = 6
```

See the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument (the *default value*, here `0`) and no block. If `h = Hash.new(0)` then `h[k]` returns the default value of zero if `h` does not have a key `k`. Initially, for example, `h` has no keys, so `h['cat']` returns `0` (and does not change `h`). If we set `h['cat'] = 9`, then of course `h['cat']` returns `9` since `h` now has a key `'cat'`.

---

Our measure of diversity for any such hash `attributes(basket)` could be the following.

```
def diversity(attributes)
  attributes.sum { |_,g| g.count { |_,cnt| cnt > 0 } }
end
```

One of the key-value pairs of `attributes` is

```
:color=>{:red=>4, :green=>4, :pink=>0, :yellow=>4}}
```

When this key-value pair is passed to `sum`'s block the block variables are set thusly<sup>1</sup>:

```
_ #=> :color
g #=> {:red=>4, :green=>4, :pink=>0, :yellow=>4}
```

The block calculation merely counts the number of values of `g` that are greater than zero.

For this particular basket:

```
diversity(attr)
  #=> 9
```

Now suppose an apple is requested with one of the following sets of attributes, which I will refer to as *requirements*:

```
{},
{ price: 1 }, { price: 2 }, { price: 5},
{ size: :S }, { size: :M }, { size: :L },
{ color: :red }, { color: :green }, { color: :yellow },
{ price: 1, size: :S }, { price: 1, color: :red }, { price: 1, color: :green }, 
{ price: 2, size: :M }, { price: 2, color: :green },
{ price: 5, size: :M }, { price: 5, size: :L }, { price: 5, color: :yellow },
{ price: 5, color: :red },
{ size: :S, color: :red }, { size: :S, color: :green },
{ size: :M, color: :green }, { size: :M, color: :yellow },
{ size: :L, color: :red }
```

`{}` indicates that any apple is acceptable.

Notice that the customer does not have the option of selecting a pink apple (as there are none) and if the customer specifies values for all three attributes there is no choice to be made.

For a given requirements hash the choice of apple to be offered is determined as follows:

```
def choices(basket, requirements)
  basket.each_index.select do |i|
    h = basket[i]
    h[:qty] > 0 && requirements.all? { |attr, val| h[attr] == val }
  end
end
```

This returns an array of indices of `basket` that are permissible choices for the given value of `requirements`. For example,

```
choices(basket, { color: :green })      #=> [1, 2]
choices(basket, { price: 1, size: :S }) #=> [0, 1]
choices(basket, {})                     #=> [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Note that the array `choices(basket, {})` does not include `3` (pink apples, for which the quantity is zero).

---

We now compute the diversity measure of the remaining basket for each possible choice, and select the apple that results in the greatest diversity score.

```
def diversity_of_remaining(basket, choice)
  new_basket = basket.each_index.map do |i|
    i == choice ? basket[choice].dup.tap { |h| h[:qty] -= 1 } : basket[i]
  end      
  diversity(attributes(new_basket))
end
```

See [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-tap).

---

Suppose:

```
requirements = { color: :red }
```

Then

```
arr = choices(basket, requirements)
  #=> [0, 5]
```

We would then compute:

```
apple = arr.max_by { |choice| diversity_of_remaining(basket, choice) }
  #=> 0
```

indicating that `basket[0]` was preferred to `basket[5]`. Note that:

```
diversity_of_remaining(basket, 0) #=> 9
diversity_of_remaining(basket, 5) #=> 8
```

See [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

---

After selling the customer a small red apple for $1.00 it would be necessary to update `basket` in preparation for the next customer:

```
basket[apple][:qty] -= 1
```

<sup>1. I've used an underscore for the first block variable to signal to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation. That is common practice.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this awesome detailed answer @caryswoveland! Question, a given line of your requirements, like this `{ price: 1 }, { price: 2 }, { price: 5},`, is that saying the customer wants to buy 3 apples, 1 at price 1, 1 at price 2, 1 at price 5, or how else is that being interpreted? I ask because where my solution fell short was that if the customer bought multiple apples with loose specifications, capacity constraints would arrive from the combination of purchased apples, so at least I found that optimizing after each individual apple wasn't working

Comment: My intention is that each of those 24 hashes would characterize a possible request by the customer. If the customer wanted a red apple, and didn't care about the price or size, that would be represented by the hash `{ color: red }`. If the customer wanted to spend $2 on a medium-size apple, but didn't care about the color, that would be `{ price: 2, size: :M }`. If the customer wanted to spend $2 on a yellow apple you could not accommodate the request, hence, no associated hash. Same if a customer wanted a pink apple...

Comment: ...If the customer wanted a medium-size green apply for $2, there is exactly one choice, so there is no need to include it among the choices.

Comment: oh I see, so the line breaks are arbitrary? each hash is what I'm looking at to represent 1 choice, correct?

Comment: Ok so then I haven't tested the code, but I'm reviewing it thoroughly. If each diversity optimization happens on a choice independently of other choices, what happens if someone orders 5 apples with price $5? should this code be able to identify then that after that order, `yellow` and `large` are no longer options thereafter?

Comment: I only looked at the effects of purchasing one apple at a time, though you could assume that five customers in a row each wanted one $5 apple (`{ price: 5 }`). (The code only responds to customer requests (`requirements`)). If you had such a stream of `5` requests, in the end  you would be left with no $5 apples, no large apples and no yellow apples, thus reducing the diversity score by three.

Comment: Ah I see yes, because this solution, if I can try to paraphrase in words, at each customer request, identifies the actual APPLE that, when removed, preserves the highest diversity store, and then removes that apple from the basket. (As opposed to my solution that removed nothing and only virtually looked at attributes.) Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes, though I haven't provided the code to remove each selected apply from inventory. If, for example, a $2 medium, green apple were selected, `h[:qty]` would be reduced by `1`, where `h = { price: 2, size: :M, color: :green,  qty: 2 }`.

Comment: Sorry for the chat, just a lot to unpack! This should be last question. You are removing an apple virtually with: `basket[apple][:qty] -= 1` right? I'm imagining a quick basket of 3 apples where there's 1 of each: `[red small, green medium, yellow large] `. If customer requests first apple, `{}, & second apple, `{}`, then for the 3rd apple, they STILL have all options, because all options are technically available. But if apples were virtually removed to max diversity score, in this case a random apple would have been removed in orders # 1, 2 & artificially limit options available for order #3

Comment: Let's suppose that at some point the basket is as follows: `basket = [a1, a2, a3]` where `a1 = { price: 1, size: :S, color: :red, qty: 2 }`, `a2 = { price: 1, size: :L, color: :green,  qty: 1 }` and `a3 = { price: 2, size: :M, color: :green,  qty: 1 }`.  For the first apple the diversity scores would be `0` for `a1` (since `a2[:qty] > 1`), `1` for `a2` (because it is the last large apple) and `2` for `a3` (because is it the last large apply and the last green apple). So we would select an `a1` apple and change `a1` to `{ price: 1, size: :S, color: :red, qty: 1 }`....(cont.)

Comment: ...For the second apple the diversity scores are `2` for `a1` (since it is the last small apple and the last red apple), and, as before, `1` for `a2` and `2` for `a3`. So we'd select `a2` and change `a2` to `{ price: 1, size: :L, color: :green,  qty: 0 }`, meaning there are no more `a2` apples. For the third apple `a1` now has a score of `3` (as it is now also the last $1 apple) and `a3` also has a score of `3` (it is now also the last green apple). We therefore would select either `a1` or `a2` (I believe my code takes the first in `basket` when there are ties)...(cont.)

Comment: ...The fourth apple requested would be the remaining apple. Is that clear?

Comment: Yes! Sorry Q may not have been clear. Consider a flow where each time an apple is added to cart, customer is shown [remaining] options to choose from. For example, if for first apple customer selects `green`, that saves, then on the next apple they add, `green` is no longer an option. However, if for first apple, customer passes `{}`, on next apple, `green` is still an option. This is why the independent selection strategy may fail. In a basket of 3 unique apples, if you place an order for 3, where the first 2 are blank, on the 3rd, you should still have all options to choose from... (cont.)

Comment: What do you mean by "blank"? I'll have a further look in the morning.

Comment: Example flow (basket of 3 apples, each with unique color): 1) add 1st apple, 2) see all 3 colors, 3) select none, 4) add 2nd apple, 5) see all 3 colors, 6) select none, 7) add 3rd apple, 8) see all colors, 9) select `red`. At this point cart is valid. Let's say now customer decides to remove the first `{}` apple because their friend said they had a color preference. At this point cart is valid with 2 apples, `{}` and `{color:red}`. Now customer adds apple again, intending to fulfill friend's preference. On the options page, now, they're NOT shown `red` anymore since that was already taken

Comment: Sorry blank  = `{}` no options are passed. I think the example flow may help. Sorry if this was from the beginning unclear! I could come up with a solution for an independent optimization, but this specific example looks at the combination and is what eluded me

Comment: Hey @caryswoveland, just following up, I realize you may just be busy, I'm just mentioning as a reminder! Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in this [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229230/max-number-of-selections)