# Optimizing for maximum number of options to show customer given collection of their existing selections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, optimization

This is a variation of an older question (linked below), that I phrased poorly so doesn't adequately address my problem.

**BACKGROUND**

Suppose there is an apple basket with apples, each of which is an `object` with a `size` attribute, and in this particular basket, we have 3 apples: `[{size:'S'}, {size:'M'}, {size:'L'}]`

In the shopping process, each time a customer adds an apple to the cart, they are given the option to select a size, but importantly, they do not have to select a size, it is an optional selector.

I'm trying to write a method, `remaining_options` that maximizes the maximum number of options a customer is shown when they add an apple to their cart, given their history of past selections. The fact that the size selection is optional is very important. Consider these 2 examples:

**Example A: Customer selects an option**

1. Customer adds 1st apple to cart
2. Customer sees prompt `Please make a size selection (optional): [S, M, L]`
3. Customer decides to select `S`
4. Customer adds 2nd apple to cart
5. Customer sees prompt `Please make a size selection (optional): [M, L]`

**Example B: Customer does NOT select an option**

1. Customer adds 1st apple to cart
2. Customer sees prompt `Please make a size selection (optional): [S, M, L]`
3. Customer skips this step
4. Customer adds 2nd apple to cart
5. Customer sees prompt `Please make a size selection (optional): [S, M, L]`

In Example B, because the customer did NOT select an option, the full set of options available is still shown. The code does not arbitrarily "remove" an apple from the option-set. In other words, this method `remaining_options` is not responsible for calculating remaining *quantity*, only remaining *options*, which it tries to maximize.

*NOTE: Of course, even though this method doesn't calculate quantity, upon real world checkout, inventory is adjusted for the next customer, again via a different method. I.e., assuming that in the examples above, customer does not make a size selection for the 2nd apple, then upon checkout...*

- *Example A, customer will receive 1 `S` apple and a 2nd apple that's either `M` or `L`, as randomly selected by other code. If customer receives `[S,M]`, then the next customer that orders an apple will only be able to add 1 apple and `remaining_options` will only return `[L]`*
- *Example B, customer will receive 2 random apples, could be `[S,M]`, `[M,L]`, `[S,L]`, as randomly selected by other code. If customer receives `[S,L]`, then the next customer that orders an apple will only be able to add 1 apple and `remaining_options` will only return `[M]`*

**COMPLEXITY**

The challenge is I want `remaining_options` to work for any given number of possible attributes (`size`,`color`,`price`, etc.) on the apple object, and any number of options for such attributes. And since selections are optional, user can decline to select `size`,`color`,`price`,etc., or select 1 (e.g., only `size`) or 2 (e.g., `size` and `price`) and etc.

With this complexity, it's important that the code *not* treat the process of adding an apple to the cart as an independent process, where the `remaining_options` is calculated by options in basket *minus* the last option selected.

The code should instead look at all the apples in the customer's cart, whether or not an option has been selected for each, and then calculating the maximum number of `remaining_options`

The solutions in the previous [posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201892/optimization-problem-showing-maximum-number-of-remaining-options-given-a-collec/66205270?noredirect=1#comment117353122_66205270) didn't work because they did the former, i.e., treated adding each apple as an independent process that removed an option from the basket.

Here's an example to clarify. Suppose the basket of 3 apples looks like this:

```
[
  {size:'S', price:1},
  {size:'M', price:2},
  {size:'L', price:2},
]
```

**Step 1 - adding the 1st apple**

Let's say `remaining_options` takes an argument of the customer's existing. So when a customer adds their 1st apple to the cart, there's nothing in the cart existing, so all options are returned

```
  basket.remaining_options([])
  => {size:['S','M','L'], price: [1,2]}
```

**Step 2 - adding the 2nd apple**

To finish up the 1st apple transaction, customer decided to select an apple with `price:2`. Then they add their 2nd apple to the cart. Since there's more than 1 apple with `price:2`, the customer's 1st choice created no capacity constraints, an again all options are shown.

```
  basket.remaining_options([{price:2}])
  => {size:['S','M','L'], price: [1,2]}
```

*NOTE: @obiruby astutely observed that although `{size:['S','M','L'], price: [1,2]}` is technically all the remaining options, they're not all selectable. For this second apple, if customer selects `M`, then the first apple has to be auto-assigned as `L` and therefore is no longer selectable. This is handled by yet another method that I already have working. So many methods... all to make this max-options optimization work!*

**Step 3 - adding the 3rd apple**

To finish up the 2nd apple transaction, customer decided to, again, select an apple with `price:2`. Then they add their 3rd apple to the cart. Now it's tricky. If this code just subtracted options selected, then on face value, `remaining_options` might return this: `{size:['S','M','L'], price: [1]}`. But this is not accurate, because when all the `price:2` apples are taken, so are all the `M` and `L` apples by default. This is why the right code needs to look collectively at existing cart. I.e., this should be the result:

```
  basket.remaining_options([{price:2}, {price:2}])
  => {size:['S'], price: [1]}
```

Note also that because of how capacity constraints work, the following should also be returned correctly by the method:

```
  basket.remaining_options([{price:2}, {size:'M'}])
  => {size:['S'], price: [1]}

  # user's 1st ordered apple has a price request
  # user's 2nd ordered apple has a size request
  # COMBO of the 2 only work if...
    # user's 1st ordered apple is the {price:2, size:'L'} apple in basket
    # user's 2nd ordered apple is the {size:'M', price:'2'} apple in basket
  # therefore if user is looking at remaining options for a 3rd apple, there's only the {size:'S', price:'1'} apple left in basket
```

So... yeah help greatly appreciated in writing this method! I have my non-working ideas in the old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201892/optimization-problem-showing-maximum-number-of-remaining-options-given-a-collec/66205270?noredirect=1#comment117353122_66205270). In looking at that proposed solution (which alas also doesn't look collectively at the existing cart), I realized that one solution could be to map out all the possible combinations of apples in basket that could be assigned to fulfill the requests of each apple in the cart, and picking the combination of assignments that yields the highest number of remaining options. But I feel like this solution would be wildly inefficient as baskets, carts, and possible options increased in size.

Comment: Are you interested in answers that change the assumptions here, or is this a whiteboarding style question? In most e-commerce applications each individual sku has all of these attributes as a single database row, instead of trying to tie 'options' into a sku. So you'd have a small apple, medium apple, and a large apple. Structuring your data differently is going to wildly change the complexity of what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Msencenb I'm not sure I understand. In this application, there's also a small apple, medium apple, and a large apple? I don't think the way the data is structured is necessarily different, just how I'm optimizing the presentation. But maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: So is the limitation by the cart or by the actual quantity of the items?

Comment: @bryanfeller limitation is by what's in the cart, compared against actual items, but quantity is controlled elsewhere so you only care about the total set of size options in the actual items, and are comparing that to the total set of size options requested in the cart, if that helps

Comment: @james can you please clarify, are you sure your desired output in step 2 is correct? Because the way I am reading it, `basket.remaining_options([{price:2}])` DOES create a capacity constraint, since either M or L size will be picked, therefore what remains would EITHER be `{size:['S','L'], price: [1,2]}` OR `{size:['S','M'], price: [1,2]}` but  logically `size:['S','M','L']` cannot be possible because either M or L must be depleted after the first `{price:2}` is picked.

Comment: @obiruby SUPER astute observation, I am updating the Question. The desired outcome is CORRECT. There is yet a THIRD method that prevents customers from selecting options that aren't possible. This third method is run each time a customer makes selection, such that for the second apple, if the select `M`, then `L` will be disabled and vice versa. This method's ONLY concern is to maximize remaining options

Comment: Is a database involved?

Comment: @RickJames yes but this method doesn't relaly need it. the basket of options is pulled from the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seams like a NP-complete problem to me, I can't prove it though ^^

The following code is only a proof of concept for you to test.

**Edit**: What the code does is: Given the "abstract items" in the client's cart and the "real items" stock in the basket, generate all the combinations of "real items" (let's call these combinations "virtual carts") that satisfy both the client's cart and the stock in the basket. Then, for each "virtual cart", simulate the remaining stock in the basket. Finally, make the union of the remaining choices of each "virtual basket".

```
require 'set'

def extract_options(basket)
  basket.each_with_object( {} ) do |item, options|
    item.each do |attr,value|
      options[attr] = Set.new unless options.has_key?(attr)
      options[attr] << value
    end
  end
end

def expand_item(item, options)
  expanded = [[]]
  item.each do |attr,value|
    opts = value.nil? ? options[attr] : [value]
    expanded = expanded.each_with_object( [] ) do |path,exp|
      opts.each { |val| exp << ( path.dup << [attr, val] ) }
    end
  end
  expanded.map(&:to_h)
end

def remaining_options(basket, cart)
  options = extract_options(basket)
  return [options] if cart.empty?
  remaining = []
  f,*r = *cart.map { |item| expand_item(item, options) }
  f.product(*r) do |cart|
    b = cart.each_with_object( basket.dup ) do |item,bask|
      break unless index = bask.index(item)
      bask.delete_at(index)
    end
    remaining << extract_options(b) if b
  end
  remaining.uniq
end

def remaining_options_union(basket,cart)
  remaining_options(basket,cart).each_with_object( {} ) do |remain,union|
    remain.each do |attr,set|
      union[attr] = Set.new unless union[attr]
      union[attr] += set
    end
  end
end
```

Your test-case is small so the calculation is quick:

```
basket = [
  {size:'S', price:1},
  {size:'M', price:2},
  {size:'L', price:2},
]

cart = []
remaining_options_union(basket,cart)
# => {:size=>#<Set: {"S", "M", "L"}>, :price=>#<Set: {1, 2}>}

cart << {size: nil, price: 2} # all attributes need to be populated
remaining_options(basket,cart)
# => [{:size=>#<Set: {"S", "L"}>, :price=>#<Set: {1, 2}>}, {:size=>#<Set: {"S", "M"}>, :price=>#<Set: {1, 2}>}]
remaining_options_union(basket,cart)
# => => {:size=>#<Set: {"S", "L", "M"}>, :price=>#<Set: {1, 2}>}


cart << {size: nil, price: 2} 
remaining_options(basket,cart)
# => [{:size=>#<Set: {"S"}>, :price=>#<Set: {1}>}]
remaining_options_union(basket,cart)
# => {:size=>#<Set: {"S"}>, :price=>#<Set: {1}>}
```

**Update:** The following code keeps the previously calculated "virtual baskets" in memory for speeding up the addition of a new item to the cart.

```
require 'set'

class Cart

  def self.extract_choices basket
    basket.each_with_object( {} ) do |item, attrs|
      item.each do |key,value|
        raise "Null valued item attribute in basket" if value.nil?
        attrs[key] = Set.new unless attrs.has_key?(key)
        attrs[key] << value
      end
    end
  end

  attr_reader :remaining_options

  def initialize basket
    choices = self.class.extract_choices basket
    
    @globs = choices # needed to unglob a null valued attribute in an item
    @attrs = choices.keys # attributes found in the items of the basket

    # The items in the basket shall have all the possible attributes populated and not null
    basket.each do |item|
      @attrs.each do |attr|
        raise "Invalid item in basket" unless item[attr]
      end
    end

    @virtual_baskets = [ basket ]
    @remaining_options = choices
  end

  def <<(item)
    # As we're using the 'Hash#==' method, each item must have all its
    # attributes set (the same ones as in the basket), no more, no less.
    item = @attrs.each_with_object( {} ) do |attr,obj|
      obj[attr] = item[attr]
    end

    # NOTE: an item with globs will multiply the number of virtual baskets
    update_virtual_baskets item

    choices = @virtual_baskets.map{|b| self.class.extract_choices b}

    @remaining_options = choices.each_with_object( {} ) do |choice, union|
      choice.each do |attr,set|
        union[attr] = Set.new unless union[attr]
        union[attr] += set
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def unglob item
    expanded_items = [[]]
    item.each do |attr, value|
      choices = value.nil? ? @globs[attr] : [value]
      expanded_items = expanded_items.each_with_object( [] ) do |pre, obj|
        choices.each { |val| obj << ( pre.dup << [attr, val] ) }
      end
    end
    expanded_items.map(&:to_h)
  end

  def update_virtual_baskets formated_item
    expanded_items = unglob formated_item
    valid_baskets = []
    @virtual_baskets.each do |basket|
      expanded_items.each do |item|
        basket.each_index do |idx|
          next unless basket[idx] == item
          bsk = basket.dup
          bsk.delete_at(idx)
          valid_baskets << bsk
        end
      end
    end
    raise "Error while adding item to cart - no stock" if valid_baskets.empty?
    @virtual_baskets = valid_baskets.uniq
  end
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
basket = [
  {origin:'IL', size:'S', color:'G', price:1},
  {origin:'SP', size:'M', color:'G', price:2},
  {origin:'SP', size:'M', color:'R', price:2},
  {origin:'SP', size:'M', color:'Y', price:3},
  {origin:'CA', size:'L', color:'G', price:1},
  {origin:'SP', size:'L', color:'G', price:4},
  {origin:'CA', size:'L', color:'R', price:4},
]

cart = Cart.new basket

cart << {price:2}
cart << {size:'M'}
cart << {origin:'SP'}
cart.remaining_options
# => {:origin=>#<Set: {"IL", "CA", "SP"}>, :size=>#<Set: {"S", "L", "M"}>, :color=>#<Set: {"G", "R", "Y"}>, :price=>#<Set: {1, 4, 3, 2}>}
cart << {price:2}
cart.remaining_options 
# => {:origin=>#<Set: {"IL", "CA"}>, :size=>#<Set: {"S", "L"}>, :color=>#<Set: {"G", "R"}>, :price=>#<Set: {1, 4}>}
```

**Possible improvements:** By adding a "quantity" to the items in the basket you should be able to reduce the size and the number of "virtual baskets". Also, if the price is a mandatory field (which makes sense) then you can "kind of" split the problem by price and make the code faster.

**Remark:** Another way to phrase what you're looking for would be: For each possible choice in each attribute (ex. `:size` is an attribute and one of its possible choices is `'S'`), does it exist a combination of items in the cart that doesn't deplete it ? Unless there exists a mathematical formula to find it quickly, you'll have to almost walk through all the possible combinations in order to be able to respond 'no' to that question...

To a certain extent, my second proposal that keeps in memory the valid "virtual baskets" of the previous iteration is a sensible way to tackle the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Taking a stab at understanding this, the crux `remaining_options` method basically says, for all possible combinations of options that meet the specifications of the various items in cart... calculate remaining options IF the currently iterated combination does exist in basket (represents a valid choice)... and then lastly since we're maximizing, join the array of remaining options in a union. Is that right?

Comment: That's right, I think that's what you were asking for. Right now I'm writing the same logic in a more usable way (keeping the previously calculated possible valid carts in memory then expanding them when adding a new item). I think you're problem may be NP-complete, thus difficult to use in production. Tell if this code gives you the output you're looking for

Comment: @fravadonna ok great, give me a day or so to examine it in detail. i think you're right about the np complete thing... but honestly you know when i started asking this question, i was like, it doesn't seem that hard, i probably am just missing something... but now that all these various answers have forced me to examine it more, not to mention research into ecommerce systems which, as others have pointed out, dont' do it this way... and gosh darn it... there may be a reason this approach is the odd one out

Comment: @james. You're right, it seams easy at first but, if I'm right about NP-completeness, it costs an arm to resolve. That may be the reason why e-commerces don't do that even if it's a good way (commercially speaking) to display things. I updated my post, if you want to take a look ;-)

Comment: thanks! I didn't have a chance to look at updated answer, but original answer did pass all my specs! i'm going to reevaluate, given this complexity, if this path is something i want to go down...

Comment: You're welcome ;-) You may want to ask about the complexity of your problem with the 'discrete-mathematics' tag of StackOverflow. People there may know a few cunning algorithms for resolving it. At least they should be able to tell you about its NP-completeness.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple of things that need to be considered before you're able to fully tackle this problem.

1. SKUs and stock

In an E-Commerce system, as was pointed out correctly in a comment, there's usually a concept of SKUs which uniquely describe a single product. So each of your unique apple types would be a separate SKU. In your simplified examples, the SKUs are for small, medium and large apples; in your "fully" example, you'd have separate SKUs for "small red apple", "medium red apple", "small green apple", "large green apple" etc. The fact that all of these are "apples" and the possible combinations of various attributes don't matter in terms of SKUs – these categorizations based on attributes is an arbitrary grouping criterion that is put on top of the list of all SKUs to make them more approachable to users of the system (be it customers, employees, tax advisors etc.).

Subsequently, each SKU has a quantity >= 0 in stock. Again, these quantities are completely independent of each other and the fact that you might say "we have 20 apples in stock" (where 5 of them are S, 11 M and 4 L) is a grouping approach that you put on top, not one that actually exists from a stock keeping perspective.

2. SKU/category assignment/locking

The 2nd issue to understand is the concept of article assignment/locking. That is, when someone adds an article to their cart, you temporarily mark the article as if it were already purchased so that it can't get sold twice. This approach is usually referred to as locking. Depending on order frequency, you then set a timeout of that lock, e.g. 30 minutes, meaning, if a purchase doesn't happen within 30 minutes, you release the lock and allow another customer to lock it (and ideally purchase it).

In a normal E-Commerce context, you would create such locks on a SKU level, but it sound like this is not the right approach in your case since you also allow users to add non-specific articles to their carts. So what you probably want is a kind of multi-level lock:

- When a user adds a non-specific article to their cart, you lock the selected quantity of all categories that the article is assigned to.
- When a user adds a specific SKU to their cart, you lock the selected quantity of the specific SKU for that user.
- You add constraints that doesn't allow any category and any specific SKU to exceed their individual current stock.

3. Distribution

The last step then is actual distribution. Here, you go from most to least specific, i.e. you start by alotting the specific SKUs, followed by articles assigned to most categories all the way to the "I don't care, I just want any apple" customers.

---

I hope this makes sense to you. I'm aware that it's highly conceptual. But it's hard to give specific answers to a somewhat generic and (apparently) theoretical use case.

Comment: yup totally! this is aligned with what i'm building. the only complexity is that i'm still trying to maximize what's shown to the customer, in a way that e-commerce systems currently do not do. For example, in most e-commerce systems, selectable options are mandatory, not optional which critically drives the complexity in this case. And in most e-commerce systems, even if options were optional, I don't feel like they maximize the way I'm trying to, they do treat it as a random apple SKU were removed, and remaining options displayed. This is where my approach is differing

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab, please see below.

You can play around with the code by copying the entire code below into a single file (say, test.rb) and then running it from the command line (ie, `ruby test.rb`)

The design is based off the idea that the problem of "maximizing the options that remain in-basket" is logically equivalent to "removing options from the basket in order of most common to least common".

```
# test.rb
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Basket
  attr_accessor :basket
  def initialize(opts={})
    @basket = opts[:basket]
  end


  def remaining_options(selected_options=[])
    return {} if @basket.empty?

    selected_options.each do |option_criteria|
      select_option(option_criteria)
    end

    print_basket
  end

  def select_option(option_criteria)
    selectable_options = @basket.select { |opt| matches?(opt, option_criteria) }
    option_to_select = most_common_option(selectable_options)
    remove_from_basket option_to_select
  end

  def most_common_option( selectable_options )
    max_matches = 0
    max_matches_idx = nil

    selectable_options.each_with_index do |option, i|
      option_matches = 0
      option.keys.each do |k|
        selectable_options.each do |opt, i|
          option_matches += 1 if option[k] == opt[k]
        end

        if option_matches > max_matches
          max_matches = option_matches
          max_matches_idx = i
        end
      end
    end

    selectable_options[max_matches_idx]
  end

  def remove_from_basket( option_to_select )
    idx_to_remove = @basket.index { |i| matches?(i, option_to_select)}
    @basket.delete_at idx_to_remove
  end

  def matches?(opt, selected)
    selected.keys.all? { |k| selected[k] == opt[k] }
  end

  def print_basket
    hsh = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }

    @basket.each do |item_hsh|
      item_hsh.each do |k, v|
        hsh[k] << v unless hsh[k].include?(v)
      end
    end

    hsh
  end
end

class BasketTest < Minitest::Test
  def setup_basket
    Basket.new basket: [
      {size:'S', price:1},
      {size:'M', price:2},
      {size:'L', price:2},
    ]
  end

  def test_initial_basket_case
    basket = setup_basket
    assert basket.remaining_options == {size:['S','M','L'], price: [1,2]}
  end

  def test_returns_empty_if_basket_empty
    basket = Basket.new basket: []
    assert basket.remaining_options([{price:2}]) == {}
  end

  def test_one_pick
    basket = setup_basket
    assert basket.remaining_options([{price:2}]) == {size:['S', 'L'], price: [1,2]}
  end

  def test_two_picks
    basket = setup_basket
    assert basket.remaining_options([{price:2}, {price:2}]) == {size:['S'], price: [1]}
  end

  def test_maximizes_options
    larger_basket = Basket.new basket: [
      {size:'S', price:1},
      {size:'L', price:2},
      {size:'M', price:2},
      {size:'M', price:2}
    ]
    assert larger_basket.remaining_options([{price:2}]) == {size:['S', 'L', 'M'], price: [1,2]}
  end

  def test_maximizes_options_complex
    larger_basket = Basket.new basket: [
      {size:'S', price:1, color: 'red'},
      {size:'L', price:2, color: 'red'},
      {size:'M', price:2, color: 'purple'},
      {size:'M', price:2, color: 'green'},
      {size:'M', price:2, color: 'green'},
      {size:'M', price:2, color: 'green'}
    ]
    assert larger_basket.remaining_options([{price:2}, {color: 'green'}]) == {size:['S', 'L', 'M'], price: [1,2], color: ['red', 'purple', 'green']}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this attempt! `test_one_pick` is short a size option though, it should still return `S, M, L` because the code shouldn't pick on behalf of the user. I think that's the challenge with an approach that purports to remove something from the basket, because nothing's technically been removed yet, so the option should persist. I noted in my comment to you in the original posting that there's another off-screen method that prevents conflicts when user actually goes to select `S, M, L` after they've made a first pick